# Find basis of $ U = \left\{ u \in \mathbb C^n |u_1+u_2 +...+u_n=0 \right\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis

I want to find basis of
$$ U = \left\{ u \in \mathbb C^n |u_1+u_2 +...+u_n=0   \right\}$$
I am writing this post because I am not sure with one thing:

If I had :
$$ Z = \left\{ z \in \mathbb R^n |z_1+z_2 +...+z_n=0   \right\}$$
then $$ Z=span([-1,1,0,...,0]^T,[-1,0,1,0,...,0]^T,...,[-1,0,...,0,1^T])$$
Ok, but If I consider complex space $\mathbb C^n$, should I add vector to basis for complex unit?
I mean instead of
$$ U=span([-1,1,0,...,0]^T,[-1,0,1,0,...,0]^T,...,[-1,0,...,0,1^T])$$
put
$$ U=span([-1,1,0,...,0]^T,[-1,0,1,0,...,0]^T,...,[-1,0,...,0,1^T],[-i,i,0,...,0]^T,[-i,0,i,0,...,0]^T,...,[-i,0,...,0,i^T])$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to define a vector space, you have to specify the set of vectors, the field of scalars, the addition operation, and the scaling operation. In this context, there are at least two ways to view $U$ as a vector space; you could say the field of scalars is $\mathbb C$ or $\mathbb R$ (and that the addition/scaling operations are the usual ones).

If the field of scalars is $\mathbb C$, then
$$
\{[-1,1,0,...,0]^T,[-1,0,1,0,...,0]^T,...,[-1,0,...,0,1^T]\}
$$
is a basis, since every element of $U$ can be uniquely written in the form $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}c_kv_k$ with $v_k$ being the $k^{th}$ vector in the above list and $c_k\in \mathbb C$.

If the field of scalars is $\mathbb R$, then
$$
\{[-1,1,0,...,0]^T,...,[-1,0,...,0,1^T],[-i,i,0,...,0]^T,...,[-i,0,...,0,i^T]\}
$$
is a basis, since every element of $U$ can be written uniquely in the form $\sum_{k=1}^{2n-2}c_kw_k$, with $w_k$ being the $k^{th}$ vector in the above list and $c_k\in \mathbb R$.

Comment: Ahh, so the background of scalars is important. Thanks for great explanation!